# Find base64 in source code with python regex

Tags: python, regex, base64

I want to find any base64 code / hash in the website source code. It can be in a JavaScript function call.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">data = get_data('aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=') ); </script>
```

or in variables.

Is there a reliable way to check this with regex?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about `please send the regex`, not a programming problem. Take a __[tour]__ to learn what [so] is about.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9/+-]+={0,2}` but that's going to get a lot of non-base64 stuff.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `re` module:

```
>>> import re
>>> my_string = """<script type="text/javascript">data = get_data('aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=') ); </script>"""
>>> re.findall("<script.*get_data\(\'(.*=).*</script>",my_string)
['aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=']
```

`BeautifulSoup` is great Utility to parse Html, take a look at it:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(my_string)
>>> soup
<html><head><script type="text/javascript">data = get_data('aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=') ); </script></head></html>
>>> for x in soup.find_all('script'):
...     print re.findall("\'(.*)=\'",x.text)
... 
[u'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ']
```